# Rails update_attributes for current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I have a boolean ajax setting that I'm updating and after update call the "current_user" var for a flash message--problem is, the current_user in the flash message contains old data (pre update-attribute).

What's the best way to refresh the current_user data without a page reload?

Comment: `"[do something on server side] without a page reload"` => the answer for this question is **Asynchronous Javascript and XML, aka AJAX**, for 99% of these
 cases

Comment: Probably just going to need to respond to the AJAX with a javascript object of some form and then update just that segment of the page.

Comment: Looks like you are mixing a few things here. `current_user` can only be accessed server side. How can you access it pre update-attribute (you cannot go back in time)? Once you update the attribute, subsequent requests will return the updated user. Though I don't think it will help, but try current_user.reload to reload the user object. If you can describe the complete flow (what happens when), we might be able to help.

Comment: Sorry, it's not an ajax issue. I call `update_attributes`, then call the flash outputting `current_user.attribute`, but it's old info, not the updated info... I'll current_user.reload

Comment: So, that works alright, but I'm also calling from a translation--so this ajax method changes locale. I'll rewrite my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely that your current_user code looks something like this:

> if session[:user_id]
>       @current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id])
>   end

In which case, the cached value would not update after you make the above update—have you tried updating current_user when you make this update so it's available when the flash happens?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. It is highly recommended to make use of comments to point out the typo , corrections or problem explanation, once you earn enough reputations.